# My list of dictionaries changes

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I have this problem with a list of dictionaries which is created during the program. I have a while loop, that in each iteration creates a dictionary and appends it to a list. On the first iteration everything is fine, but on the second one the dictionary that is created somehow becomes the second member of the list AND the first member, so what I have is a list of dictionary in the size of 2, with the same dictionaries in each member of the list.

```
while(question!="done"):
    answers=[]
    print "Please enter a question, write 'done' to finish"
    question=raw_input()
    if(question!="done"):
        mil["Question"]=question
        print "How many possible answers do you want this question to have?"
        numOfAnswers=raw_input()
        mil["Number of Answers"]=int(numOfAnswers)
        for i in xrange(int(numOfAnswers)):
            print "Please enter the next answer:"
            answer=raw_input()
            answers.append(answer)
        mil["Answers"]=answers
        print "_________________________________________________"
        for i in xrange(int(numOfAnswers)):
            print i+1,". ", answers[i]
        print "_________________________________________________"
        print "Please enter the value of the correct answer"
        correct=raw_input()
        mil["Correct Answer"]=correct
        questions.append(mil)
```

That's the while loop. `mil` is a dictionary, `questions` is a list.

Does someone know what the problem is?

Comment: A dictionary is mutable and is not passed by value. I.e.: are you creating a new dictonary on every iteration or are you recycling the same one? Please provide some code

Comment: A bit confused with your statement: `the dictionary that is created somehow becomes the second member of the list AND the first member,` what do you mean by `AND first member` ?

Comment: In the list there are  2 elements: in the first element and the second one there is the same dicitonary! The newer one

Answer (score 0):

`mil` is just a pointer to a dictionary that you are (probably, hard to say without the code) overwriting with whatever new dictionary you are creating every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating new `mil` in every iteration.So Simply do

```
if(question!="done"):
    mil = {}
```